# Get number of idle CPU counts in python windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, multithreading, cpu-usage

In multi-threading programming, wanted to start threads only according to number to idle CPUs available.

How can I get number of idle CPUs in python windows.

In linux

```
import os
os.getloadavg()
```

seems helpful.

Is that anyway to get in python on windows env ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This works for python with a version >= 2.6

```
import multiprocessing

multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count

Comment: I believe that is to find number of CPU cores. But is there any to find the number of "IDLE" Cpu cont ?

Comment: try the first example in following link. 
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/13028/os.getloadavg

Comment: Thank you. But that was I mentioned 'getloadavg' is available only for Linux. I am checking for windows.